# extract html inside <p class=" without simplehtmldom

Tags: php, dom, curl, domdocument

i want to extract html inside `<p class="js-swt-text"` without simplehtmldom

bellow is the working example i did with simplehtmldom:

```
<?php

include('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = file_get_html("http://blabla.com");
foreach($html->find('.js-swt-text') as $ret) {
    echo $ret;
}

?>
```

please help me to do with domdocument

```
<?php
$html = file_get_contents("http://blabla.com");
```

and echo html from every `<p class="js-swt-text"`

Comment: you need to make an attempt first, http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

Comment: i attempt many times and also check answers of many question on http://stackoverflow.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
$html = file_get_contents("http://blabla.com");
$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom->loadHtml($html);
$xpath = new DomXpath($dom);
$items = $xpath->query('//p[@class="js-swt-text"]');
foreach ($items as $item) {
   echo $item->textContent . "\n";
}
```

Comment: You should check that the HTML of the page that you're trying to load is valid.

Comment: the output only shoes text, how to show tags inside like <strong>?

Comment: same output from this also i am tring other methods